# weird problem - OAuthException - Access Token

Tags: button, postback, facebook-c#-sdk

Yesterday I noticed problem with my application. Everything was fine, but now something is wrong with button and postbacks.
I get error:

(OAuthException) (OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

while im trying use .Get("me") info @ postback.

I set a watch on reguest.params(signed_request) and everyting is fine, but when I click button on my app to make postback, my request.params(signed_request) value is nothing.

Any ideas how to solve problem ?

(im using 4.2.5 (?) sdk and 5.0.6 show me the same error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass access token parameter to FacebookWebClient constructor:

new FacebookClient(FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken);